# Копия объекта при двухсторонней привязке ngModel

Tags: angular2

Есть инпут, в который из базового объекта `Order` приходит значение имени пользователя:

```
<input value="{{Order.Name}}" [(ngModel)]="Order.Name" />
```

В инпуте используется двухсторонняя привязка `ngModel` для корректировки базового объекта, когда имя пользователя в инпуте нужно поменять.

Если меняется значение имени в инпуте, необходимо вывести какое-нибудь сообщение.

Kак сохранить первоначальное значение инпута, чтобы с ним сравнивать новое значение (для вывода сообщения)?

Пробовал делать копии первоначального объекта, но при `[(ngModel)]` меняется и первоначальный объект и все его копии. По факту получается, что не с чем сравнить новое значение.

Односторонняя привязка `[ngModel]` не подходит, так как в конечном счете нужно, чтобы базовый объект изменился, для отправки на сервер.

Comment: Ну как вариант, при инициализации первоначального значения сохранять его копию тем же angular.copy([object]). Или же если интирисует свойство name объекта order то можно присвоить только его значение (я так понимаю это примитив и копировать здесь ничего не нужно)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Kак сохранить первоначальное значение инпута, чтобы с ним сравнивать новое значение (для вывода сообщения)?` 
Вы просто не правильно скопировали объект. Копировать надо было как минимум так:

```
const copyObj = Object.assign<`тип Order`, `тип Order`>('новый объект', this.Order);
```

В этом случае Вы получите копию и изменение базового `Order` никак влиять не будут.

По основному вопросу: если Вам нужно вывести сообщение в случае, если что то поменялось в импуте, то можно воспользоваться формой (`<form>`). У неё есть свойство `dirty`. Соответственно, если у инпута это свойство будет выставлено, то можно выводить ваше сообщение об изменении.